# GoDaddy hoarding domains. What is my legal recourse?

Tags: internet

I want to purchase a domain: curion.com 
It is unavailable because it is held by godaddy (as shown on whois.net) 
Question is, Can a web hosting company hoard a domain name to itself. Is it even allowed? The domain doesnt function either. 
How do I legally pursue this matter? What is the law?

Whois details:

Domain Name: CURION.COM 
Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC 
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 146
Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com
Name Server: NS1.JACKSONNATIONAL.COM
Name Server: NS2.JACKSONNATIONAL.COM
Name Server: NS3.JACKSONNATIONAL.COM
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 11-feb-2013
Creation Date: 11-jul-2002
Expiration Date: 11-jul-2018

Comment: GoDaddy isn't hoarding it, because they don't own it. Jackson National Life Insurance is the registr**ant**; GoDaddy is the registr**ar**. It appears to be a misconfigured domain.

Comment: This question can be improved by editing it to add some request to verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain you mention has godaddy as its registrar, but the *registrant* (I.e. 'owner') is 'Jackson National Life Ins Co' according to godaddy's own whois server.

To answer your question: a person or other entity can register as many domains as it likes. Absent a trademark or other name-related dispute, you have no grounds to dispute a registered domain simply because you think it's being 'hoarded'.

Comment: I think there actually are rules about *registrars* hoarding domains; however, those rules are a matter of contracts and agreements between entities in the DNS system, like ICANN, registries, and registrars.

Comment: Is there a technical name/term to the practice of registering or "owning" domains that one doesn't use, just to force someone else interested in the domain to pay way above normal prices? (effectively holding the domain hostage) --- And are there legal pathways against that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a private registration, but where the name is forwarded to a public entity.  If the registrant had chosen to let godaddy host the domain, and put up non-affiliated content - then the privacy would have been maintained.

GoDaddy isn't hoarding this one; it's just a poorly executed private registration.